# Are axioms more important than definitions?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics, philosophy-of-logic

To prove a theorem in mathematics we usually use our axioms, definitions and other already proved theorems. Suppose we wante to prove a specific theorem and we haven't prove any other theorem and also we don't use any other definition except the definitions that are contained in the statement we want to prove. That is we want to prove from scratch (using just the axioms) the statement "If P then Q" where we have only defined what P, Q and the conditional mean. Are the axioms (using also rules of inference) enough to prove that statement in the system?

**Does adding definitions change the system?**

Suppose the statement "The numbers 2,4 are even" where we have defined "even=any number greater than 2". This clearly shows that just by changing one definition we have at least change the truth value of a statement. In other words theorems in an axiomatic system are also sensitive to definitions. That is the system changes not only by axioms but also from the definitions. So does this mean that we are not allowed to add definitions in a system or we can just only such definitions that don't contradict the previous irrespective of the fact that these new definitions may alter the number of theorems that can be proved?

Comment: Theorems are not sensitive to definitions, labeling something else "even" does not change the theorems, only relabels their abbreviated formulations. The role of definitions in a formal system is mostly abbreviation for convenience.

Comment: Yes, they are. A definition is a "formal abbreviation": it does not "add" nothing new to what can be already proved from the axioms.

Comment: In your example, if we stay with the definition of "Even", we have that **not-Even(2)**, because we can easily prove that "2 is not greater than 2". Thus, if we add to the theory the statement **Even(2)**, we have a contradiction.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So what I can prove depends only on the axioms? But to define new term should I first prove that it somehow makes sense to add this "abbrevation"? For example first we show that there exists a unique number that can be obtained by adding and multiplying the entries of the matrix and we call it determinant. Can we do the same with every other definition? In other words is every defined entity proved to exist by the axioms before we define it?

Comment: @Conifold If definitions serves only as abbrevations then this mean that every theorem is proven only using axioms and rules of inference. But in mathematics I can't see why is that the case. We define objects in the way we like. E.g. we define functions, integrals, matrices etc and no one asks "does this object can proved to exist (in the system) by the axioms and it happens to have a name". Otherwise I can define whatever I want and do math on it. E.g. I can define arbitrary a "trunction" to be a process that assings 3 numbers in the vertices of an equilateral triangle" and is just fine.

Comment: What we like only matters for which theorems we choose to focus on, and how we wish to present them. But all derivative terms can be eliminated from statements by replacing them according to definitions, and theorems reformulated in basic terms only. In particular, all theorems in ZFC can be reduced to statements about sets and elements, be they about ellipses, numbers, vector spaces or trunctions. Of course, the result will not be attractive to a human, but the difference is purely decorative. All you can do "arbitrarily" is pick theorems and abbreviations that are more appealing intuitively.

Comment: @Conifold So the axioms indeed postulate that such objects exists. Now makes sense. But do postulates of ZFC give existence to certain objects? I mean how do we know which objects to define? It seems that somehow "magically" we know what objects ZFC axioms give existence and we just name them. But when we are teached mathematics all teachers start to give definitions in a manner that it seems that an object is created. Unless you study mathematics or philosophy no one would know that in fact all the mathematical objects we are used and seem intuitive actually exist in ZFC.

Comment: ZFC no more gives existence to functions than The Lord of the Rings gives existence to hobbits. One can choose to believe that functions, or hobbits, exist platonically, but that is their philosophical preference, it is not ZFC's doing. They are "created" in the sense that they become available for discourse after being defined, but nothing at all in that discourse depends on whether or not one chooses to believe that they ideally pre-existed beforehand. That too is a decoration.

Comment: @Conifold Consider the analogy of a game. Axioms are the rules of the game, objects are the players, theorems are the moves. If I keep the rules the same and create new objects (create new players) then doesn't the game change? Doesn't the moves now depend also on the objects? If definitions serve as abbrevations for existing players then yes of course they don't affect the theorems. But this is what I am asking to get clarified. Is the definition in mathematics only an abbrevation? Is e.g. "function" an abbrevation for a player (object) that already exists?

Comment: The analogy is faulty. Formal system is more like a single player game, there is no "creating" new players. You can "create" new objects, but they are like "new" chess configurations, "new" only in the sense that people start paying attention to them when they are singled out and named. The board and the pieces are the same. Definition in *formal* mathematics is only an abbreviation, but that does not mean that any objects already exist or ever existed or will ever exist. The "creation" is only a metaphor.